# How to design a "data usage calculator" for a brand new smartphone users

Tags: mobile, info-visualisation, measuring

What are some ways wireless carriers can help smart phone buyers visualize how much data they will need so they pick a suitable data plan option?

Various carriers provide data usage calculators: eg

https://my.ee.co.uk/data-calculator/

But this misses one very important criteria:  where do you use your smartphone ? - because if you use it on your home wireless network your data usage will be dramatically different from using just the mobile connection.

So what criteria actually matter in the design of the calculator ?

Comment: Currently you've written this as a 'consumer question' so it will get closed.  However if you re-word it as 'How do I demonstrate to users what 1GB of data actually looks like ?' its a useful question which mobile phone companies might want to take note of on their websites.

Comment: PS - the key criteria is how much you'll be using the phone away from your home wi-fi. If you use it mainly at home then you won't be using much of the mobile data.

Comment: @PhillipW, would you be kind enough to rewrite it?

Comment: I would suggest to get the lowest GB possible and simply use the phone however you please. Check the data usage once a week to make sure you do not suffer overages. You *should* be able to add more GB at a reasonable price if needed. The first few weeks of owning a smartphone seem to cost the most data because you end up playing with all of the features. If you plan on watching a lot of YouTube then expect to plow through your data limit and pay overages. Assuming you have WiFi then you should be able to mitigate your mobile data usage.

Comment: There's also data usage calculators offered by most wireless carriers if you want to do a rough estimate. Just google for "data usage calculator"

Comment: Re-written. Feel free to edit further.

Answer (score 2):

### Most users can relate to digital media

Sometimes I convert the cost of various items into NetFlix subscriptions to emphasize how much my wife doesn't need that new pair of shoes costing the same as 14 months of NetFlix.  Most users are aware of how much media they consume on their phone which is good since this also happens to be the main thing taking up data.

One major hurdle to using a number of pictures, songs, and movies is the wide range of formats used to shrink them down.  This means that **two different people could view the same number of each item and one consumes 10GB while the other only consumes 1GB of data**.

Similarly, the difference between standard and high definition (HD) video is so huge that it may even make sense to ask the user if they plan on streaming HD or standard video feeds.

**Any data estimation calculator must clearly communicate this fact to the user.**

The link to the sample calculator was a little too cumbersome.  Even if we only focus on digital media it has such a wide margin of error that is bigger than all the other types of data usage combined.

### Only focus on non-wifi usage

Make it clear to the user that in order to correctly estimate the proper data usage plan they should only count the number of media files they consume while not connected to a wifi network at home or at work.  The demo calculator had slider positions for "a little", "medium", "a lot" which is bad!  This can mean different things to different people so ask for an actual count or number of hours they plan on streaming the different types of media.

[image]